# Cannot install rust-src: "Found argument 'component add rust-src' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context"

Tags: rust, rustup

I'm on MacO Big Sur, just have the latest stable Rust installed via:

> curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh

No, I don't use Homebrew. Then I want to compile [xv6-rust](https://github.com/connorkuehl/xv6-rust). It needs the nightly version, with extra component **rust-src**. I already switch to nightly:

> $ rustc --version
>
> rustc 1.60.0-nightly (777bb86bc 2022-01-20)

Now the problem is: how to install rust-src?

> $ rustup component add rust-src
>
> error: error: Found argument 'component' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this > context
>
> USAGE:
> rustup-init [FLAGS] [OPTIONS]

Comment: `rustup-init` is the installer for Rustup itself -- it shouldn't be on your `$PATH`, or even really exist once you've installed Rustup. Perhaps you downloaded the installer script and added that to your path? The file you download from `sh.rustup.rs` is an installer for Rustup, not Rustup itself.

Comment: OK. After running `locate rust-init`, seems like I forgot that rustup-init was already installed via homebrew. Then I uninstalled it: `brew uninstall rustup-init`. Another issue come, when running `rustup component add rust-src` again, I got this: "zsh: command not found: rustup-init"

Comment: Found the culprit. In my .zshrc, there's this line: `alias rustup=rustup-init`. I didn't exactly remember doing that. Or perhaps mixing manual installation with homebrew isn't always a good idea? Removed that line and now rustup works fine.